# PrimeNG Listbox, all the item were selected before even clicked. When used [multiple]="true" the list is shown as selected

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, primeng, angular6

**details.component.html**

```html
<p-listbox [options]="availableDimensions" [(ngModel)]="selectedDimensionsName" filter="filter"
  [style]="{'width':'210px','font-size':'12px'}"
  [listStyle]="{'min-height':'250px','max-height':'250px','font-size':'12px'}">

  <ng-template let-dimension pTemplate="item">
    <span>{{dimension}}</span>
  </ng-template>

</p-listbox>
```

**details.component.ts**

```js
availableDimensions: string[];
selectedDimensionsName: string[];

onChangeFilterCriteria() {
  this.service.getDimensionName()
    .subscribe(name => {
      this.availableDimensions = name;
      console.log(this.availableDimensions)
    });
}

// console output of availableDimensions = ["Brand Digital", "Brand Equity", "Catch All", "D-MOS Display", "D-MOS Video", "Direct", "Display", "Display - Historical", "Display-Endemics", "Endemic Non-Retention", "Endemic Retention", "Launch Campaigns", "Organic Search", "Organic Social", "Other Refferer", "Paid Search", "Paid Search(Brand)", "Paid Search(Non-Brand)", "Regional Digital", "Retargeting", "Unknown"]``
```

[this the current output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmEhd.png)

expected Behavior 
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/listbox

Please check Advanced (Multiple, Checkbox and Filter)

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gzorbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts I added my code in stackblitz, it shows primeng module is not found, but when I run it I can see it. But I am using the same code.

Answer (score -1):

selectedDimentionName should be just a string. Remove array on it.

```
selectedDimentionsName:string;
```

Should fix your issue.

Example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-listbox)